# Automatic Python logging

Tags: python, logging

This is just a quick and simple question to clarify my study of the logging module. It looks like  nothing gets logged anywhere without a log request [i.e., logging.info('Hi there')]. So if something shows up in my logs, and I did not make that request, it is buried somewhere in library code. Or, to put it another way, there is no such thing as 'automatic' logging. Somehow, somewhere, a log request has to be made by a human. Correct? Thanks.

Comment: I would say, yes. But it is not impossible to "automatically" get info about run of script, like it is doing "poor mans dubbuger" `pysnooper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if something shows up in my logs, and I did not make that request, it is buried somewhere in library code. Or, to put it another way, there is no such thing as 'automatic' logging. Somehow, somewhere, a log request has to be made by a human. Correct?

Correct.

Somewhere a Python package that you've imported (note: might be a nested dependency rather than direct import) has not followed the practice of using [`NullHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#library-config) and instead decided to configure its own logger to emit something to stdout without you asking it to.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know I am not going crazy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what are you going to create. 
For example, if you are going to develop a Flask app where you want to log activities corresponding with databases, you can implement it in one place and 'listen' to all events. 
I haven't done it yet (and was asking myself the same question), but I found [this tutorial](https://sagarkaurav.hashnode.dev/tracking-database-changes-in-flask-sqlalchemy-for-audit-logs).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).